# Page break on print with title

Tags: html

I have a `<table>`.

```css
table {
  page-break-inside: auto
}

tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto
}

thead {
  display: table-header-group
}

tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Test
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test 2
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Another one</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Test
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test 2
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want, when I print, that the title follows with the rest and breaks at the correct spot, because sometimes, the title stays at the end of a page, and the `<table>` sits on the other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the page-break properties (and especially the `avoid` value) are [not very well supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=page-break%20properties) by most browsers.

In the meantime, you can use the following solution:

- move your title inside your table by using the `caption` tag
- add `page-break-before: always;` in your table element CSS

```css
table {
  page-break-inside: auto;
  page-break-before: always; /* add this line */
}

tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto;
}

thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Test
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test 2
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <caption>
    <h2>Another one</h2>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Test
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test 2
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Although this will work, please note that this solution is not the most sustainable, as you will potentially print more pages than necessary.

Also, don't forget to set the media attribute of your link tag to "print", like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```